# Redis lookup with a default value

Tags: ruby, null, redis

I have some code to perform a redis lookup, but if the key to look up either doesn't exist or there's an issue connecting to Redis at all, it will use a default value.

The logic currently looks like this:

```
begin
 redis = Redis.new(:url => url)
 returned_value = redis.get(key)
 if returned_value == nil and defined?(default) != nil
   default
 else
   returned_value
 end
rescue Exception => e
  if default
    debug "Connection to redis failed with #{e} - Returning default value of #{default}"
    default
  else
    raise(Puppet::Error, "connection to redis server failed - #{e}")
  end
end
```

It feels like there might be a simpler way of doing this, right now this code feels a little wordy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all *NEVER* rescue `ExceptionError`. If you want a to rescue from any runtime exception, just omit exception class, otherwise you might catch `SignalException` which happens upon ruby process received some signal (e.g. SIGTERM) and instead of behave correctly you will silently skip that.

So, your rescue part should look actually like this:

```
begin
  # ...
rescue SocketError, Redis::CannotConnectError => e
  raise Puppet::Error, "connection to redis server failed - #{e}" unless default
  debug "Connection to redis failed with #{e} - Returning default value of #{default}"
  default
end
```

Now your main block can be also improved:

```
begin
  Redis.new(:url => url).get(key) || default
rescue
  # ...
end
```

Notice that redis returns either `String` or `Nil`, e.g.:

```
Redis.current.set(:x, 123)
Redis.current.get(:x) # => "123"

Redis.current.set(:x, false)
Redis.current.get(:x) # => "false"
```

So, summing all above together, you can form that into a method:

```
def redis_get(key, url:, default: nil)
  Redis.new(:url => url).get(key) || default
rescue SocketError, Redis::CannotConnectError => e
  raise Puppet::Error, "connection to redis server failed - #{e}" unless default
  debug "Connection to redis failed with #{e}; Return default: #{default}"
  default
end
```

Comment: Fantastic, that looks a lot cleaner. However my spec failed with a test where the redis server connection could not be found, so I added SocketError to the rescue then everything was green. I added that as an edit to the answer, other wise thanks for your fix, I'll keep this in mind next time :)

Comment: Yeah, it's totally fine to add SocketError as well. :D

Comment: Sorry, I saw that I can simply approve too late. Anyway. One note to your edit - there were no need in `begin` block. You can (and in this case should) rescue method's body... No need for extra level of depth. And for the sake of history, one might want to rescue `SocketError` as it's got raised when socket can't get ip address. e.g. when you specify `:url => "redis://surprise"` and `surprise` can't be resolved. So it's not actually redis connection issue, it' general networking issue.

Comment: Cool, works perfectly, accepted! :)